# Is there any way to move complete Google Drive to another Google Drive at once?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business

I know we can easily migrate files from Google Drive to Google Drive via Share option. But, here my problem is I want to move my domain account drive complete data to another domain account drive. So, is there any way available, I can move entire Google Drive at once?

All kind of suggestions are welcome here.

Comment: Do you have "content manager" access to a Team Drive?

Comment: Do you have a G Suite account? Do you have a Google One account?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to interpret what you mean by "domain account drive", but it sounds like you have accounts in two different domains, which would only be possible if you had a G Suite account. If that is the case:

1. Create a Team Drive, in the G Suite account.
2. Add the other account to the Team Drive with Manager or Content Manager access.
3. Move your files into the Team Drive from the sending account.
4. Move the files out of the Team Drive to the receiving account.

(For future readers, note that the nomenclature "Team Drive" [will change to "Shared Drive" in a month](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/04/shared-drives.html).)

---

If you don't have access to a Team Drive, my top suggestion is to contact Google Drive support for help (this requires a subscription to Google One), to ask if they can do it.

The main issue is transferring *ownership* of your files to the new account. If that doesn't happen, the files will still be stored in the old account, and one could accidentally permanently delete them if one isn't aware of that. Simply sharing all your files (which can be done by first pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) will not change the ownership, and it is impractical to individually change the ownership on every file. Changing the ownership of a folder doesn't change the ownership of the files inside it.

One (imperfect) way to migrate an account is to:

1. Sync your files to a computer using Backup and Sync.
2. Disconnect the sending account from the computer.
3. Sign in to Backup and Sync with the receiving account, and **merge** the files on the computer with the receiving account's *My Drive*. (Note that this will use a lot of data if you have a lot of files.)

Although the ownership of all offline files will migrate, the reason why this is imperfect is that the ownership of Google Docs will not change. You would need to look through all the files that the new account doesn't own (by searching `-owner:me` at the top of the Google Drive website (note the minus sign)), then change the ownership of your Google Docs from the sending account. This may be feasible if you only have a few Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two different domain account and in between their Google Drives you want to migrate data. Now, you want to move entire Google Drive at once, which is possible with help of Google Takeout also. You can download all data at once in ZIP format on your system. After that, upload the downloaded data in destination Google Drive. It is also one of the simplest and convenient way of migrating data between the drives.

Comment: Can I transfer Shared With Me folder and Trash folder also from one Google Drive to another using this Google Takeout method that you have suggested above?