# Migrate to another GSuite account with same domain

Tags: google-drive, google-account, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator, google-workspace

I work for '**B**' which is run along with '**A**' and 'C' by the same authority. '**B**' wanted GSuite and 'A' offered to help by adding the domain to their GSuite account. So *a.edu* had a GSuite account under which *b.edu* and *c.edu* were added and GSuite products used all these days.

Now *b.edu* wants to have a separate GSuite account since *a.edu* could control settings for *b.edu* that **B** does not want, under current scenario. I understand *b.edu* can be removed from the current GSuite account and *b.edu* can get a GSuite for Education but what about the current data in email and google drive?

Is there a way to move the content of *b.edu* accounts on Current GSuite to the new Gsuite account for *b.edu*, without having to download / export each user's data to a local system and then upload them into the new Gsuite accounts?

To avoid losing access, we thought of creating a new account on *b2.edu*, transferring all files and then moving the domain. But that seems too tedious all new accounts would have to be created, new accounts to be remembered by each user and then share, add to drive and all that mess.

How do we get a new GSuite account independently for *b.edu* without losing any data?

At this point It looks like I am confused...

TL;DR *Is it possible to Remove a domain from a GSuite account and then get a separate GSuite for that domain without losing data?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer files from one Google Drive account to another?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/139116/how-to-transfer-files-from-one-google-drive-account-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

Try MultCloud, it's a [cloud storage manager](https://www.multcloud.com/) and based on the web. I've used it to migrate my G Suite files before, but haven't tried the emails. Anyway, you can take a look.

1. Add the current G Suite account and the new G Suite account to MultCloud
2. Choose the current G Suite account as the source
3. Choose the new G Suite account as the target
4. Click on the 'Transfer' button to start the task

The whole process will be done in the background, which means you can close the web page when you launched the task successfully.

PS: In my experience, MultCloud will not keep share information while transferring files.

Comment: Thanks @Jaguarr for the answer. Will it work if both the previous and new G Suite account have the same username and domain. like atulbhat@domain.com for both accounts as login? Since I want to move domain.com to a new GSuite account, We are planning on having same domain so will that work?

Comment: @AtulBhatS I don't think two G Suite accounts can have the same username and domain, is it possible? Or are you saying that these two accounts are under the same admin account?

Comment: I got it clarified with Google. I have to remove the domain from GSuite account and then get GSuite for that domain once the removal is complete and clean. Otherwise it will create conflicts is what I was told. Thanks!